# Is work with MySQL variables atomic and user-specific?

Tags: mysql

on my site, I use this queries to update specifid record and get back its id. It works fine, but I am concerned about what will happen if two users access my site at the same time. Is the variable @update_id user-specific or not? Do I need to worry about something going wrong (like two users getting the same id, although they updated different record or something like that) with this approach? Should I use transactions to prevent such a scenario? Thanks for all the answers.

```
SET @update_id := 0;
UPDATE `table`
SET column=$column,
      id=(SELECT @update_id := id)
      WHERE column2=$column2
      LIMIT 1;
SELECT @update_id;
```

Comment: It's sessioned, i mean: by connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MySQL "user-defined variable" like `@update_id` in your example, is specific to the connection. No other users or connections can access or modify the variable.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

User variables are connection-specific.

Using variables like that is going to have problems if you lose your connection and it is automatically re-established for you (for instance, by the [Perl mysql interface](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3amysql#mysql_auto_reconnect)).
A stored procedure is better solution if you are worried about this.